# Check if title has empty space in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How does one check if the title, generated by `wp_title()` has empty space in front of it? I have found how to trim it with `trim()`

```
<?php echo trim(wp_title('', false)); ?>
```

But, like with [setting a `wp_title()` for home page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title#Covering_Homepage), I'd like to put this in the `functions.php` file, so that  it's not in my header. So far I have

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'trim_wp_title' );
function trim_wp_title( $title ) {
    if( /* check if $title contains empty space */ ) {
        $title = echo trim(wp_title('', false));
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to do the check at all, your function can be simplified down to:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'trim_wp_title' );
function trim_wp_title( $title ) {
    return trim($title);
}
```

`trim` will just leave the string as it is if there's nothing to trim off of it.

Comment: This does it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
$string = " Here is a leading space";
if (substr($string, 0, 1) === ' ')  {
    echo 'Yes, i have leading space';
}
```